# How can I prevent a package from being automatically removed in order to install another one?

Tags: 11.04, package-management, synaptic, aptitude

This is the example: I want to install elementary-desktop (from PPA), but it requires to remove esound in order to install pulseaudio (which I removed because it was causing problems with many apps). I already pinned both esound and pulseaudio and held them through `sudo aptitude hold esound` and `sudo aptitude hold pulseaudio` but, in Synaptic, the prompt still states that esound must be removed. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I wouldn't force such a thing, dependencies are there for some reason. Visit their IRC channel or file a feature-request at https://launchpad.net/~elementaryart

Answer (score 2):

Elementary I believe only recommends pulseaudio. What you could do is install via the command line using `sudo apt-get install --no-recommends elementary-desktop`, or use Synaptic and simply unmark esound/pulseaudio when elementary-desktop is selected for installation.

If it is not a recommendation, then you could simply install the packages you want (that the metapackage depends on), giving you at least the majority of the Elementary experience, minus pulseaudio.